# Send push notification of events to my iPhone PHP

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification

I'd really love to send to myself (and my colleagues) push notifications for different events (new revision in svn repos, new to-do item in our project-management system, and so on)

Is there any app out there which can we use for that? I don't want to develop a specific app for that purpose (but, of course I'll implement the server-side code to send notification).

Last thing, I'd prefer to use PHP so a service which allow API calls using PHP would be the perfect match.

I've found that [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/api.php) could be a good solution for me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boxcar](http://help.boxcar.io/kb/developers/sending-yourself-notifications) does exactly this — and it looks like someone's written [a PHP class](http://help.boxcar.io/discussions/developers/15-php-class-to-send-notification-in-boxcar) that talks to the Boxcar API as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Push Inbox](http://www.getpushinbox.com) is a pretty cheap and decent service. Simply send an email and get a push notification.